# Getting Bootstrap subnav to animate

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing here. I'm trying replicate the dropdown behavior of http://voky.com.ua/showcase/sky-mega-menu/examples/demo-personal.html on a Boostrap nav.

What I have is

```
.nav > li.menu-item-has-children ul.dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
}
.nav > li.menu-item-has-children:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

and it's not working.

Comment: would be nice if you could replicate your code on http://www.bootply.com/new# so we can help you faster :)

Comment: Have you included bootstrap? Without more details we cannot tell what is going on? Also the code replication @BastianW mentioned would be nice also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css");

/* NOT ON MOBILE PLEASE !!! */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  li.dropdown.scale > .dropdown-menu {
    display:block;
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  }

  li.dropdown.scale:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }

  li.dropdown.scale:hover {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown scale">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Bootstrap sets the `.dropdown-menu` class to `display: none;` by default, you need to override that value with `display: block !important;`. Add `opacity` instead and add your transitions to the bootstrap default classes.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    display: block !important; /* this is needed to override the default display: none; defined in bootstrap. */
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
    -o-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
}
.open > .dropdown-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

Here's a working fiddle with the similar navigation affect. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/grmf4ddr/